# why in the output javascript is sending else statement rather than if else

Tags: javascript, if-statement

```
const day = "sunday";

if (day === "monday") {
  console.log("plan course structure");
  console.log("go to coding meetup");
} else if (day === "tuesday") {
  console.log("prepare theory videos");
} else if (day === "wednesday " || day === "thursday ") {
  console.log("write code example :D");
} else if (day === "friday") {
  console.log("Record videos ");
} else if (day === "saturday " || day === "sunday ") {
  console.log("enjoy the weekend ");
} else {
  console.log("not a valid day :>)");
}
```

output coming in console :-

not a valid day :>)
why in the console javascript is sending else statement rather than else-if  .

console.log("enjoy the weekend ");

Comment: because `"sunday" !== "sunday "` (note the `" "`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be easy to feel silly in situations like this, but it's an easy and common mistake to make.

when it comes to dealing with strings with semantic meaning, I normally always use a constants data structure:

```
const DAYS = {
  MONDAY: 'monday',
  TUESDAY: 'tuesday',
  WEDNESDAY: 'wednesday',
  THURSDAY: 'thursday',
  FRIDAY: 'friday',
  SATURDAY: 'saturday',
  SUNDAY: 'sunday',
};

const day = DAYS.SUNDAY;

if (day === DAYS.MONDAY) {
  console.log('plan course structure');
  console.log('go to coding meetup');
} else if (day === DAYS.TUESDAY) {
  console.log('prepare theory videos');
} else if (day === DAYS.WEDNESDAY || day === DAYS.THURSDAY) {
  console.log('write code example :D');
} else if (day === DAYS.FRIDAY) {
  console.log('Record videos ');
} else if (day === DAYS.SATURDAY || day === DAYS.SUNDAY) {
  console.log('enjoy the weekend ');
} else {
  console.log('not a valid day :>)');
}
```

With something like this, you eliminate the risk of mistyping repeated strings and it makes it so that you only change the string in one place if you ever need to change it.

Hope this helps.